# Google Maps: How to make a marker only clickable when the user is close enough?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, location

So in short, I have a map with a lot of markers on it and at the moment if you click one of the markers it shows an info page about the location. Now I need these markers to only be clickable when the user is close enough to them. At the moment the onClickListener on the markers looks like this:

```
if (marker.getTitle().equals("Hal A")) {
                      Intent halaIntent = new Intent(MapS.this, activity_hala.class);
                      startActivity(halaIntent);
                  }
```

Now I would put another if statement with `(distanceEcolab < 5)` for example and I would calculate the distance with the `SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween` tool. 
Right now I do it like this:

```
        final LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setInterval(2000);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                super.onLocationResult(locationResult);
                if (locationResult == null) {
                    return;
                }
                mLastKnownLocation = locationResult.getLastLocation();
                LatLng lastKnownLatLng = new LatLng(mLastKnownLocation.getLatitude(), mLastKnownLocation.getLongitude());
                distanceHala = SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(lastKnownLatLng, HalA);
                mFusedLocationProviderClient.removeLocationUpdates(locationCallback);
            }
        };
```

Now I tried this and I don't get any errors and the app doesn't crash, but I'm still able to click the markers even when I'm not close enough to them.
This is my first time using Android Studio and Java, so explain it like I'm 10.
Btw, I don't even know for sure that the problem is in the code I just showed.

Full Code:

```
package com.example.discoverkoelak;

import ...

import static com.google.maps.android.SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween;

public class MapS extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    private double distanceHala;
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationProviderClient;

    private List<AutocompletePrediction> predictionList;

    private Location mLastKnownLocation;
    private LocationCallback locationCallback;
    private final float DEFAULT_ZOOM = 18;



    private View mapView;
    private Marker kaka;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);


        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.MapS);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        mapView = mapFragment.getView();

        mFusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(MapS.this);
        Places.initialize(MapS.this, ("MY_API_KEY"));
        ImageView legendeBtn = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.merkar);
        legendeBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent maptoLegende = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), activity_legende.class);
                startActivity(maptoLegende);
            }
        });


        final AutocompleteSessionToken token = AutocompleteSessionToken.newInstance();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 51) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                getDeviceLocation();

            }
        }


    }
    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private void getDeviceLocation() {
        mFusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Location>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Location> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            mLastKnownLocation = task.getResult();
                            if (mLastKnownLocation != null) {
                                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(mLastKnownLocation.getLatitude(), mLastKnownLocation.getLongitude()), DEFAULT_ZOOM));
                            } else {
                                final LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
                                locationRequest.setInterval(2000);
                                locationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
                                locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
                                locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                                        super.onLocationResult(locationResult);
                                        if (locationResult == null) {
                                            return;
                                        }
                                        mLastKnownLocation = locationResult.getLastLocation();
                                        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(mLastKnownLocation.getLatitude(), mLastKnownLocation.getLongitude()), DEFAULT_ZOOM));
                                        mFusedLocationProviderClient.removeLocationUpdates(locationCallback);
                                    }
                                };
                                mFusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback, null);

                            }
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(MapS.this, "Laatste gekende locatie kan niet worden ontvangen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }



    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {





        int height = 120;
        int width = 90;
        BitmapDrawable bitmapdraw=(BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker_dark);
        BitmapDrawable bitmapdraw2=(BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker_aula_0);
        BitmapDrawable bitmapdraw3=(BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker_research_0);
        BitmapDrawable bitmapdraw4=(BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker_residentie);
        BitmapDrawable bitmapdraw5=(BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker_ontspanning);
        BitmapDrawable bitmapdraw6=(BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker_mobiliteit_1);
        BitmapDrawable bitmapdraw7=(BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker_research_1);
        BitmapDrawable bitmapdraw8=(BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker_mobiliteit_0);
        BitmapDrawable bitmapdraw9=(BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker_administratie);


        Bitmap b=bitmapdraw.getBitmap();
        Bitmap b2=bitmapdraw2.getBitmap();
        Bitmap b3=bitmapdraw3.getBitmap();
        Bitmap b4=bitmapdraw4.getBitmap();
        Bitmap b5=bitmapdraw5.getBitmap();
        Bitmap b6=bitmapdraw6.getBitmap();
        Bitmap b7=bitmapdraw7.getBitmap();
        Bitmap b8=bitmapdraw8.getBitmap();
        Bitmap b9=bitmapdraw9.getBitmap();
        Bitmap smallMarker = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, width, height, false);
        Bitmap aulas = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b2, width, height, false);
        Bitmap research = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b3, width, height, false);
        Bitmap residenties = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b4, width, height, false);
        Bitmap ontspanning = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b5, width, height, false);
        Bitmap mobiliteitU = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b6, width, height, false);
        Bitmap researchU = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b7, width, height, false);
        Bitmap mobiliteit = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b8, width, height, false);
        Bitmap administratie = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b9, width, height, false);
        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);


HERE I STATE THE COORDINATES OF ALL THE MARKERS LIKE THIS:
        final LatLng HalA = new LatLng(... , ...);


        //Code die markers zet en ze klikbaar maakt.
        //Hal A
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(HalA)
                .title("Hal A")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(ontspanning)));
        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {
                  if (marker.getTitle().equals("Hal A")) {
                      Intent halaIntent = new Intent(MapS.this, hala.class);
                      startActivity(halaIntent);
                      return false;
                  }
                  return false;
              }
          }
        );

        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(stuvo)
                .title("Stuvo")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(administratie)));

        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(bib)
                .title("Bib")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(administratie)));

        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(acco)
                .title("Acco boekenhandel")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(administratie)));

        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(rectoraat)
                .title("Hal Rectoraat")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(administratie)));

        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(spina)
                .title("Spina")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(mobiliteit)));

        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(stilleRuimte)
                .title("Stille ruimte")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(ontspanning)));

        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(A301)
                .title("Aula Stijn Streuvels (A301)")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(aulas)));

        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(weetkelder)
                .title("Weetkelder")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(researchU)));

        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(fietsena)
                .title("FietsenA")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(mobiliteitU)));

        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(labos)
                .title("Labo's (gang 3)")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(research)));


        //gebouw B
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(B422)
                .title("B422")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(aulas)));


        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(puc)
                .title("puc")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(research)));

        //gebouw c
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(C611)
                .title("C611")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(aulas)));

        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(gang7)
                .title("Gang 7")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(research)));

        //gebouw E
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(E1001)
                .title("Aula Andreas Vesalius (E1001)")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(aulas)));

        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(vaardigheidscentrum)
                .title("Vaardigheidscentrum")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(research)));

        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(IRF)
                .title("IRF")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(research)));

        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(fietsene)
                .title("fietsene")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(mobiliteitU)));

        //residenties
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(spoelberg)
                .title("Spoelberg")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(residenties)));

        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(studentendorp)
                .title("Studentendorp")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(residenties)));

        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(corona)
                .title("Corona")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(residenties)));

        //andere
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(IICK)
                .title("IICK")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(research)));

        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(almaZweetkelder)
                        .title("Alma & Cantor en Zweetkelder")
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(ontspanning)));

        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(ecolab)
                .title("Ecolab")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(ontspanning)));

        //Afstand berekenen tussen laatst gekende locatie en PoI's
//        LatLng lastKnownLatLng = new LatLng(mLastKnownLocation.getLatitude(), mLastKnownLocation.getLongitude());
//        final double distanceEcolab = SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(lastKnownLatLng, ecolab);
//        final double distanceHala = SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(lastKnownLatLng, HalA);

        final LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setInterval(2000);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                super.onLocationResult(locationResult);
                if (locationResult == null) {
                    return;
                }
                mLastKnownLocation = locationResult.getLastLocation();
                LatLng lastKnownLatLng = new LatLng(mLastKnownLocation.getLatitude(), mLastKnownLocation.getLongitude());
                distanceHala = SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(lastKnownLatLng, HalA);
                mFusedLocationProviderClient.removeLocationUpdates(locationCallback);
            }
        };




        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
              @Override
              public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {
                  if (marker.getTitle().equals("Ecolab")) {
                      Intent ecolabIntent = new Intent(MapS.this, activity_ecolab.class);
                      startActivity(ecolabIntent);
                  }

                  else if (marker.getTitle().equals("Alma & Cantor en Zweetkelder")) {
                      Intent AlmaIntent = new Intent(MapS.this, activity_acz.class);
                      startActivity(AlmaIntent);
                  }

                  else if (marker.getTitle().equals("IICK")) {
                      Intent IICKIntent = new Intent(MapS.this, activity_iick.class);
                      startActivity(IICKIntent);

                  }

                  else if (marker.getTitle().equals("Corona")) {
                      Intent coronaIntent = new Intent(MapS.this, activity_corona.class);
                      startActivity(coronaIntent);
                  }

                  else if (marker.getTitle().equals("Studentendorp")){
                      Intent studentendorpIntent = new Intent(MapS.this, activity_studentendorp.class);
                      startActivity(studentendorpIntent);
                  }

                  else if (marker.getTitle().equals("Spoelberg")) {
                      Intent spoelbergIntent = new Intent(MapS.this, activity_spoelberg.class);
                      startActivity(spoelbergIntent);
                  }

                  else if (marker.getTitle().equals("fietsene")) {
                      Intent fietseneIntent = new Intent(MapS.this, activity_fietsene.class);
                      startActivity(fietseneIntent);
                  }

                  else if (marker.getTitle().equals("IRF")) {
                      Intent IRFIntent = new Intent(MapS.this, activity_irf.class);
                      startActivity(IRFIntent);
                  }

                  else if (marker.getTitle().equals("Vaardigheidscentrum")) {
                      Intent vaardigheidscentrumIntent = new Intent(MapS.this, activity_vaardigheid.class);
                      startActivity(vaardigheidscentrumIntent);
                  }

                  else if (marker.getTitle().equals("Aula Andreas Vesalius (E1001)")) {
                      Intent E1001Intent = new Intent(MapS.this, activity_e1001.class);
                      startActivity(E1001Intent);
                  }

                  else if (marker.getTitle().equals("Gang 7")) {
                      Intent gang7Intent = new Intent(MapS.this, activity_kantoren.class);
                      startActivity(gang7Intent);
                  }

                  else if (marker.getTitle().equals("C611")) {
                      Intent C611Intent = new Intent(MapS.this, activity_c611.class);
                      startActivity(C611Intent);
                  }

                  else if (marker.getTitle().equals("puc")) {
                      Intent pucIntent = new Intent(MapS.this, activity_puc.class);
                      startActivity(pucIntent);
                  }

                  else if (marker.getTitle().equals("B422")) {
                      Intent B422Intent = new Intent(MapS.this, activity_b422.class);
                      startActivity(B422Intent);
                  }

                  else if (marker.getTitle().equals("Labo's (gang 3)")) {
                      Intent labosIntent = new Intent(MapS.this, activity_labo.class);
                      startActivity(labosIntent);
                  }

                  else if (marker.getTitle().equals("FietsenA")) {
                      Intent fietsenaIntent = new Intent(MapS.this, activity_fietsena.class);
                      startActivity(fietsenaIntent);
                  }

                  else if (marker.getTitle().equals("Weetkelder")) {
                      Intent weetkelderIntent = new Intent(MapS.this, activity_weetkelder.class);
                      startActivity(weetkelderIntent);
                  }

                  else if (marker.getTitle().equals("Aula Stijn Streuvels (A301)")) {
                      Intent A301Intent = new Intent(MapS.this, activity_A301.class);
                      startActivity(A301Intent);
                  }

                  else if (marker.getTitle().equals("Stille ruimte")) {
                      Intent stilIntent = new Intent(MapS.this, activity_stil.class);
                      startActivity(stilIntent);
                  }

                  else if (marker.getTitle().equals("Spina")) {
                      Intent spinaIntent = new Intent(MapS.this, activity_spina.class);
                      startActivity(spinaIntent);
                  }

                  else if (marker.getTitle().equals("Hal Rectoraat")) {
                      Intent rectoraatIntent = new Intent(MapS.this, activity_rectoraat.class);
                      startActivity(rectoraatIntent);
                  }

                  else if (marker.getTitle().equals("Acco boekenhandel")) {
                      Intent accoIntent = new Intent(MapS.this, activity_acco.class);
                      startActivity(accoIntent);
                  }

                  else if (marker.getTitle().equals("Bib")) {
                      Intent bibIntent = new Intent(MapS.this, activity_onthaalbib.class);
                      startActivity(bibIntent);
                  }

                  else if (marker.getTitle().equals("Stuvo")) {
                      Intent stuvoIntent = new Intent(MapS.this, activity_secstuvo.class);
                      startActivity(stuvoIntent);
                  }

                  else if (marker.getTitle().equals("Hal A")) {
                      if (distanceHala < 5){
                        Intent halaIntent = new Intent(MapS.this, hala.class);
                        startActivity(halaIntent);}
                  }
                  return true;
              }
          }
        );













        if(mapView != null && mapView.findViewById(Integer.parseInt("1")) != null)  {
            View locationButton = ((View) mapView.findViewById(Integer.parseInt("1")).getParent()).findViewById(Integer.parseInt("2"));
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) locationButton.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, 0);
            layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
            layoutParams.setMargins(0,0,40,180);

        }

        // kijken of gps signaal aanstaat
//        LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
//        locationRequest.setInterval(10000);
//        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
//        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder().addLocationRequest(locationRequest);
        SettingsClient settingsClient = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(MapS.this);
        Task<LocationSettingsResponse> task = settingsClient.checkLocationSettings(builder.build());
        task.addOnSuccessListener(MapS.this, new OnSuccessListener<LocationSettingsResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LocationSettingsResponse locationSettingsResponse) {
                getDeviceLocation();
            }
        });

        task.addOnFailureListener(MapS.this, new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                if(e instanceof  ResolvableApiException) {
                    ResolvableApiException resolvable = (ResolvableApiException) e;
                    try{
                    resolvable.startResolutionForResult(MapS.this, 51);
                } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }}
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add distance check in `onMarkerClick()`, like that:

```
...
@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {

    double distancetoMarker = SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(lastKnownLatLng, marker.getPosition());
    if (distancetoMarker > MAX_DISTANCE_TO_CLICKED_MARKER) {
        return;
    }

    if (marker.getTitle().equals("Ecolab")) {
        Intent ecolabIntent = new Intent(MapS.this, activity_ecolab.class);
        startActivity(ecolabIntent);
    }
...
```